# html2canvas white space at the bottom

Tags: html, css, canvas, html2canvas

I wrote this code in react

```
      function download(element) {
        html2canvas(element).then((canvas) => {
          window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className='box' onClick={(e) => download(e.target)}>
      <h2>
        <img src={logo} alt='logo' draggable='none' />
        {title}
      </h2>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
```

and css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500|Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap');

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#root {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 2em;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
}

.boxContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2em;
}

.box {
  background-color: #212120;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0.9em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box h2,
.box p {
  --color: rgb(218, 218, 218);
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: var(--color);
}
...
```

The purpose of this code is to open a screenshot of a element. The code works however at the bottom the screenshot there is a white space (around 2px high).
How can I remove it ? Thank you :)

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Hh3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This space comes from `h2` tag. It is required by letters like "g" or "y". You can use `line-height: 0` to remove it.

In many cases "2px bottom problem" comes from the `img` tag. It is `display: inline` by default. You can use `display: block` and move it out of `h2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function download(element) {
    html2canvas(element, {
      height: element.offsetHeight - 1,
    }).then((canvas) => {
      window.open(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
    });
}
```

Edit: I fixed it using by manually changing the height